# Spring / Maven load file from classpath

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

in my resources folder:

```
src/main/resources
```

I have two files the `application.properties` file and a JSON file `app.schema.json`

I have the following function:

```
private File loadSchema(String schemaName) throws JsonSchemaMissingException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = JsonSchemaValidator.class.getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("app.schema.json")).getFile());

        if (!file.exists()) {
            log.LogErrorWithTransactionId("", "file does not exist " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            throw new JsonSchemaMissingException("file does not exist");
        }
        return file;
    }
```

If I run `mvn spring-boot:run` it successfully find the file. If I run:

- `mvn package`
- `java -jar app.jar`

I get a `NullPointer` because the following file does not exist:

```
/home/XXX/Docs/project/XXX/file:/home/ghovat/Docs/project/XXX/target/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/app.event.json
```

In my pom.xml in build I added with and without the following setting:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Neither way it works. It can reach the file if I run `mvn spring-boot:run`
but also if I run `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage` and `java -jar target/app.jar` It doesnt find the file.

I checked all the docs and tried several different ways to load the file but either way it doesnt find it.

How can I make the file available?

Comment: The problem here is that your `app.event.json` is not accessible as a file, as it is inside the app.jar file. You must access it as a resource. Your code doesn't show wht happens with the result of `loadSchema`, but it should be able to handle `InputStream`. As long as you stick to InputStream you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ropert Scholte mentioned to fix it I used Inputstream to load instead of loading it as File. 
With the Code below I fixed it:

```
private Reader loadSchema(String schemaName) throws JsonSchemaMissingException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = JsonSchemaValidator.class.getClassLoader();
    InputStream fileStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(schemaName);

    if (fileStream == null) {
        log.LogErrorWithTransactionId("", "file does not exist ");
        throw new JsonSchemaMissingException("file does not exist");
    }
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return reader;
}
```

Note since I use the file for validating a JSON Schema I needed to convert the Inputstream to a reader object

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your `src/main/resources` directory to the classpath in your pom.xml using its relative path:

```
 <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

You can read more about it [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried it with the absolute path as well I receive the same error. `file does not exist /home/XXX/Dokumente/project/XXX/file:/home/XXX/Dokumente/project/XXX/target/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/app.event.json`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check inside jar if it contains the mentioned file in classes folder. Also you can try below code to load the file from classpath.

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(<file_name>)
```

If possible then keep that file outside the jar in some folder location and set that location as classpath when executing the jar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i run `mvn spring-boot:run` the file exists inside of the jar. If I just run `mvn package` and `java -jar XXX.jar` it doesnt exist:
`/home/XXX/Dokumente/project/XXX/target/classes/XXX.json` if I unpack the jaar maually I see the file in `BOOT-INF/classes/`